# php - array_reverse efficiency

Tags: php, arrays, performance

I read on the PHP site (http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-shift.php) that the use of `array_reverse` and `array_pop` was more efficient than using `array_shift`.

I was wondering, for `array_reverse`, is it only more efficient if the `$preserve_keys` parameter is set to `true`? It seems like for redoing the keys, it would be necessary to do an iteration, but I wasn't sure whether the same iteration would be necessary to preserve keys and reverse the array.

My primary question is:
Is `array_reverse(array_pop(array_reverse($arr, true)),true)` more efficient than `array_shift($arr)`, and if so, how does `array_reverse` avoid the iteration required by `array_shift`?

Comment: pretty sure it's because array_reverse just sets a reverse flag telling php to read using the end pointer rather than the beginning pointer, then you pop off the contents of the end pointer, and then set the reverse back so it resets the reverse flag.

Comment: `larger array`, as per the comment. just because it's a comment on the php site doesn't mean it's gospel. "large array" could mean MILLIONS of entries. you'll probably find that reverse(pop(reverse())) is less efficient on smaller arrays...

Comment: @MarcB Thanks, I realize that, but with the goal of scalability in mind, I like to consider the more efficient solution.

Comment: well, benchmark your particular php implementation. figure out just how much of a speed diff between both versions exists, and then decide if it applies in your situation. e.g. if array_reverse gets slower than the a(p(a())) version at around 5000 elements, take a look at how big your array ever gets. no point in making more complex code if you only ever have 200 elements.